# Play! Framework Websockets with Chrome 17

Tags: google-chrome, playframework, websocket

I'm trying to set up a simple Websockets server with the Play! framework (1.2.4).  All that should happen right now is the client should connect, receive a "Hello User" message, then the socket should close.  I am getting different results with different browsers: Safari works as expected; Chrome 17 causes an error:

```
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: The outbound channel is closed
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
at play.mvc.WebSocketInvoker.invoke(WebSocketInvoker.java:28)
at play.server.PlayHandler$WebSocketInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:1332)
...
```

Here is the server-side code:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.WebSocketClose;
import play.mvc.Http.WebSocketEvent;
import play.mvc.Http.WebSocketFrame;

import java.util.*;

import models.*;
import play.data.validation.*;


public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }

    public static class WebSocket extends WebSocketController {
        public static void hello(String name) {
            outbound.send("Hello %s!", name);
        }
    }
}
```

/ws is routed to Application.WebSocket.hello.
The client-side javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('sendbutton')
        .addEventListener('click', sendMessage, false);
    document.getElementById('connectbutton')
        .addEventListener('click', connect, false);
    document.getElementById('disconnectbutton')
        .addEventListener('click', disconnect, false);
}

function writeStatus(message) {
    var html = document.createElement("div");
    html.setAttribute('class', 'message');
    html.innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById("status").appendChild(html);
}

function connect() {

ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/ws?name=User");

    ws.onopen = function(evt) { 
        writeStatus("connected");
    }

    ws.onclose = function(evt) {
        writeStatus("disconnected");
    }

    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
        writeStatus("response: " + evt.data);
    }

    ws.onerror = function(evt) {
        writeStatus("error: " + evt.data);
    }
}

function disconnect() {
    ws.close();
}

function sendMessage() {
    ws.send(document.getElementById('messagefield').value);
}
```

Is the handshake response wrong?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the latest version from the master branch. 1.2.4 was released before the latest version of websockets protocol was released. As a result, this has been a moving target ever since, as browsers added the newer versions, and the web servers have tried to catch up.

This should now be stable as it has become a standard from W3C, and the Websocket support is direct from Netty, rather than from Play itself.